# Can't validate XML with multiple XSD schemaLocation

Tags: java, xml

I try to validate XML with several XSD inside of it and validation is OK, but it shouldn't be so.

For example, my XML is

```
<cnt:FirstXsd xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                    xmlns:cat="CommonTypes"
                    xmlns:cnt="FirstXsd"
                    xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2001/06/soap-envelope"
                    xsi:schemaLocation="FirstXsd FirstXsd.xsd">
   <cat:DocumentID>TEST_TEXT</cat:DocumentID>
   <cnt:FirstDoc>
      <cnt:DocBody>
         <sec:SecondXsd xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                            xmlns:cat="CommonTypes"
                            xmlns:sec="SecondXsd"
                            xsi:schemaLocation="SecondXsd Second.xsd">
            <cat:DocumentID>TEST_NUMBER</cat:DocumentID>    
         </sec:SecondXsd>
      </cnt:DocBody>
    </cnt:FirstDoc>
</cnt:FirstXsd>
```

And `<cat:DocumentID>TEST_NUMBER</cat:DocumentID>` is required

I check with that code

```
public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    File xsds=new File[]{new File(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("First.xsd").getFile()),new File(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("Second.xsd").getFile())};
    File xml = new File(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("test.xml").getFile());

    System.out.println(validation.validateXMLByXSD_Array(new StreamSource(new StringReader(xml)),xsds));
}


public boolean validateXMLByXSD_Array(Source xml, File[] xsds) {

    Source[] sources = new Source[xsds.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < xsds.length; i++) {
        sources[i] = new StreamSource(xsds[i]);
    }
    SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
    try {
        Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(sources);
        Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
        validator.setErrorHandler(new ForgivingErrorHandler());
        validator.validate(xml);
    }  catch (SAXException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return true;
}
```

So, my problem is everytime I get none errors If I delete requeired `<cat:DocumentID>` or not. But, If I delete full `<cnt:DocBody>` which is required from First.xsd I get error.

It seems, that only First XSD which occurs ti JVM in XML is checking. When I try to debug, I see that my schema have both xsd inside it like is written [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/validation/SchemaFactory.html#newSchema(javax.xml.transform.Source[]))

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:cat="CommonTypes:1.0" xmlns:cnt="FirstXsd:1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="FirstXsd:1.0" elementFormDefault="qualified" version="1.0">
    <xs:import namespace="CommonTypes:1.0" schemaLocation="CommonTypes.xsd"/>
    <xs:element name="FirstXsd" type="cnt:FirstXsdType"/>
    <xs:complexType name="FirstXsdType">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="cat:BaseDocType">
                <xs:attribute name="DocumentModeID" type="cat:DocumentModeIDType" use="required" fixed="TEST_TEXT"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="ContainerDocType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Element1" type="cat:Element1" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="Element2" type="cat:Element2" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="Element3" type="cat:Element3" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="DocBody" type="cat:DocBodyType"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="DocBodyType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:any processContents="skip"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:cat="CommonTypes:1.0" xmlns:sec="SecondXsd:1.0" targetNamespace="SecondXsd:1.0" elementFormDefault="qualified" version="1.0">
    <xs:import namespace="CommonTypes:1.0" schemaLocation="CommonTypes.xsd"/>
    <xs:element name="SecondXsd" type="sec:SecondXsdType"/>
    <xs:complexType name="SecondXsdType">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="cat:BaseDocType">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="Element1" type="cat:Element1"/>
                    <xs:element name="Element2" type="cat:Element2"/>
                    <xs:element name="Element3" type="cat:Element3" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: You will need to share the two XSD files. Probably best to cut them both down to the minimum definitions required for this scenario.

Comment: @kimbert, It's not a problem. It looks something like that. But It doesn't matter how it looks. Problem in Java, because, If I would not chose SecondXsd in java code, I get none exception but If I not chose FirstXsd, I get both exception for absent every elements from both XSD's

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for providing the xsds. It would be useful to see the definition of CommonTypes.xsd as well. However, I think I can make a useful comment based on what you have posted.

You claim that cat:DocumentID is required, but it does not appear anywhere in the content of cnt:FirstXsd. Does CommonTypes.xsd define a global element with name 'DocumentID'? Even if it does, your XSD does not refer to it so it is not required as a member of cnt:FirstXsd.

I do not think this is a defect in the Java implementation of XSD validation. Please explain what you are trying to achieve, so that we can suggest a better solution.

Comment: It is possible that I make a mistake while create that XSDs but main problem not in DocumentID. Problem consists in that When `validator` starts validate my XML which have complex structer it defince my FirstXsd, check it and.... even doesn't check inner SecondXsd complex type. Validator says that everything OK when I fill every required its fields. But If I leave empty all fields from SecondXsd ( in first and second xsdx there are about 50 fields) it is everything Ok anyway.

Comment: But, if I wouldn;t add FirstXsd into `File xsds` I get errors about FirstXsd and SecondXsd like `SAXParseException; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'cnt:FirstXsd'.`  for example

Comment: I do not think you understand how XSD validation works. That makes it very difficult to explain what you have done wrong (esp. when you have not actually said what you are trying to do). Can I suggest that you go back to basics. Create some very simple XSDs and play around with them until you understand how things work. Then return to this problem - even if you cannot solve it, you will be able to explain the problem more clearly.

Comment: Its a good advice, go to basics, but I can understand it. And If I validate onle SecondXsd with `validator` in Java, I get any error when XML wouldn`t have any require fields, the same situation with FirstXsd.

Comment: I found where the problem is. It was in the <xs:sequence>
            <xs:any processContents="skip"/>
        </xs:sequence>. Because of that, Java doesn't validate SecondXsd. So. You can drop your answer and create new with that conclusion. Otherwise, your advise about basics help me)